# Double clicking to open a file doesn't work with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio code and it works fine except that double clicking the file doesn't seem to open the file. Instead the Program just opens with an Untitled.txt screen.

Right click -> Open with code also works.

How do I make it work? I am using Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't the case some versions back, but now it seems, that it actually **is** the expected behaviour. The developers *intentionally* do not register VSCode as the default open handler (don't ask me why).

But maybe there is a workaround. Try the following steps:

> **1.** Try to associate the filetype(s) with another app, and then again to VSCode.
>
> **2.** If setting to other editors and returning to VSCode still opens Untitled-1.txt, then you could
>
> **3.** try reinstalling VSCode, and then reset it. When resetting, confirm that there is only *one* VSCode in the choice list.

It also could be, that you'll need to reboot your machine. Finally, you'll possibly also want to take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17779) on GitHub.

Hope you can solve it this way.